# loading a text file with complex numbers using i instead of j

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a new python programmer so excuse me if it was a silly problem.
I'm loading a txt file containing complex numbers. This is a 2x4 sample from the actual large file txt file (i is used as the imaginary number instead of j):

```
0.633399474768199 - 0.0175109522504542i 0.337208501994460 + 0.00414157519417569i    0.462845433000816 + 0.0311199272434047i 0.248496359856117 + 0.000929998413548307i
0.633719938420320 - 0.0168830372084714i 0.364374358580293 + 0.0247026480558120i 0.460808199213633 + 0.0346904985858835i 0.251160695519198 - 0.00257247233248499i
```

tried to load the file using:

```
data = np.loadtxt(path, dtype=np.complex_)
```

appearently the error is only solved when I delete all the spaces before and after + and - between the real part and imaginary part for all values, and I also need to replace i by j.

```
0.633399474768199-0.0175109522504542j   0.337208501994460+0.00414157519417569j
```

I can do this manually (not an option for large data), is there any easier way to load it? Becase I'm not sure how to delete the spaces before and after + and -, without affecting the spaces between separate values, which is not consistance between all values, some values got more spaces between them than other values, example of three values with different spaces between them:

```
0.633830049713846 - 0.0164809219396847i 0.375552117859690 + 0.00970977484227810i    0.473980903316675 + 0.0360707252275126i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is probably write a new file with the desired format. For instance, you could do:

```
with open(yourinputfile, 'rt') as f, open('output.txt', 'wt') as g:
    for line in f:
        pairs = [k.replace(' ', '') for k in line.split('i')][:-2]
        g.write('j '.join(pairs) + 'j\n')
```

The expression `line.split('i')` divides your input string at each `i` character. For instance, if the line is

```
 '0.633399474768199 - 0.0175109522504542i 0.337208501994460 + 0.00414157519417569i    0.462845433000816 + 0.0311199272434047i 0.248496359856117 + 0.000929998413548307i'
```

`split(i)` would produce the list of strings

```
['0.633399474768199 - 0.0175109522504542', ' 0.337208501994460 + 0.00414157519417569', '    0.462845433000816 + 0.0311199272434047', ' 0.248496359856117 + 0.000929998413548307', '']
```

Note the empty string at the end of that list. The `[:-2]` is a way to pick up all the strings except that last one. And then `k.replace(' ', '')` removes all the spaces in each pair.

Then `'j '.join(pairs) + 'j\n'` uses the `join` method of the string class to tack a `j`  (note the space) onto the end of each of the pairs except for the last. We tack on a `j` and a newline to the last one, and then write that to a new file.

After doing this, you can use `np.loadtxt` as you originally intended.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution without creating a new file :

```
import numpy as np

with open(path, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    
data = []
for line in lines:
    #remove spaces before and after "+" and create a list around "i" character
    line2 = [elem.replace(" + ", "+") for elem in line.split("i")[:-1:]]
    #id with "-"
    line2 = [elem.replace(" - ", "-") for elem in line2]
    # add a "j" character at the end of each element
    line2 = [elem+"j" for elem in line2]
    data.append(line2)

#convert to a complex numpy ndarray
data = np.array(data, dtype=np.complex128)
```